# Aviso Git: LF will be replaced by CRLF

Tags: git

Criei um arquivo chamado tests.html dentro de uma pasta.

Depois de digitar:

```
git add tests.html
```

Apareceu a mensagem:

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in testes.html
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

A primeira vez que adicionei um arquivo não apareceu mensagem nenhuma, mas agora apareceu...

O que significa **LF** e **CRLF**?

O que este aviso significa ou o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Terminador de linha

- LF => Line Feed (ASCII 10)
- CRLF => Carriage Return + Line Feed (ASCII 13+10)

Isto é a forma como as linhas de texto de arquivo terminam. Ou com apenas um caractere ou com os dois. Em geral o primeiro é preferido em um sistema operacional (Linux por exemplo) e o segundo preferido em outro (Windows).

Terminador de linha é a forma como é indicado o fim de cada linha de um arquivo texto. Precisa de algum caractere para determinar que a linha acabou. Em geral esse caractere não é mostrado no texto em editores e listagens mas ele está lá no arquivo. Sem ele como saberia que a linha acabou? Podemos dizer, bem a grosso modo, que isto é o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que está lá.

Alguns editores possuem uma opção para mostrar esses caracteres de forma especial.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ideal é manter sempre o mesmo padrão (alguns softwares podem até ter problemas por causa disto).

## Como o Git lida com isso

Se não há consistência o Git pode converter por você.

Esta mensagem só está te avisando que fez a conversão para você.

Você pode mudar este comportamento com:

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

mas o mais comum é deixar como

```
git config core.autocrlf input
```

Você provavelmente gravou o arquivo com um terminador de linha que não é o desejável. Ou talvez o arquivo tenha vindo de outro lugar que tem um terminador diferente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com terminador de linha @bigown?

Comment: Veja na edição se melhorou.

Comment: Agora deu certo... Utilizei o git config core.autocrlf input e o aviso parou de aparecer... Muito obrigada!

Comment: Sim, bastante... ^_^

Comment: e quanto ao `safecrlf` e `eol`?

Comment: @BernardoA.DalCorno o que é que tem?

Comment: @Maniero vi um pessoal comentando que `safecrl=false` seria melhor do que `autocrlf` (ou seja, ele vai alterar os arquivos sem se preocupar?). E nao entendi mto bem a relaçao de `eol` com esses dois lendo a documentação

Comment: Alguém pode me explicar o que esse comando faz e porque ele resolve o problema ? 

Comando:  git config core.autocrlf input

Answer (score 9):

Vamos lá.

> O que significa LF e CRLF?

**LF** significa *Line Feed* e **CRLF** significa *Carriage Return Line Feed*. Ambos são formas de quebra de linha diferentes nos arquivos. O LF é adotado por sistemas baseados em Linux/Unix e o CRLF é adotado pelo Windows.

Este tipo de aviso:

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in testes.html

É bem [comum](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) quando em um mesmo repositório há pessoas trabalhando no mesmo arquivo com Linux e outras com Windows. Como muitos editores não respeitam o padrão de quebra de linha adotado no arquivo, acabam sobreescrevendo a quebra de linha existente, gerando esta confusão.

Para nossa sorte, o Git consegue lidar com este cenário convertendo de um tipo de quebra de linha para outro. No aviso acima, o Git quer dizer que você perderá a quebra de linha unix LF depois do commit (sendo substituído pelo formato Windows CRLF). O Git, neste caso, não espera que você use o formato unix LF no Windows.

A flag do Git que nos ajuda a controlar isto é o `core.autocrlf`. Ele funciona [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf):

```
core.autocrlf=true:      core.autocrlf=input:     core.autocrlf=false:

        repo                     repo                     repo
      ^      V                 ^      V                 ^      V
     /        \               /        \               /        \
crlf->lf    lf->crlf     crlf->lf       \             /          \      
   /            \           /            \           /            \
```

A [recomendação geral](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/2387977) para Windows é deixar esta opção como `true`.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Pois [resumindo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/2387977):

- Usar `core.autocrlf = true` se planeja usar este projeto no Linux/Unix e no Windows (não querendo configurar seu editor para usar o formato Unix)
- Usar `core.autocrlf = false` se planeja usar o projeto apenas no Windows (ou se você tem configurado seu editor para o usar o formato de quebra de linha Unix)
- Não usar `core.autocrlf = input` a menos que você tenha um bom motivo (exemplo: está usando utilitários unix no Windows)