# Git - problema de quebra de linha entre diferentes Sistemas Operacionais

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Estou tentando corrigir um problema relativo ao Git, é um problema de quebra de linha em arquivos que foram enviados de um sistema operacional baseado em DOS e posteriormente alterado em um SO baseado em UNIX.

O que acontece: quando eu altero 'n' linhas em meu SO Linux, por exemplo, o arquivo: "models.py", e executo o comando `git diff`, aparece apenas uma linha alterada.

Esse problema é devido a quebra de linha dos SOs serem diferentes...

Alguém já passou por esse problema e conseguiu resolver? Alguma dica?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44373/101

Answer (score 1):

Os sistemas reconhecem a quebra de linha de formas diferentes. Você pode definir um padrão no próprio arquivo nas configurações, a quebra de linha dos sistemas podem estar distintos.